# самый короткий перебор паролей

Tags: соревнование

Напишите максимально короткий код для перебора паролей, в котором можно задать интервал, количество знаков и используемые символы.

Comment: @KromStern замечание верное ) Ну вот, как-то исправил.

Answer (score 9):

### Haskell, 25 символов

```
g s l=forM [1..l]$const s
g s l=forM [1..l] (\x->s) -- альтернативный вариант
```

Здесь параметр `s` - строка-алфавит, `l` - требуемая длина.

Для работы нужен модуль [`Control.Monad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Monad.html)

Функция `forM` рекурсивно проходит по `Traversable` структуре и применяет функцию, возвращающую монаду, к каждому элементу, после чего "собирает" внутри монады структуру, состоящую из результатов функции.

Структура тут - список. Монада - тоже список (монада-список отвечает за перебор всех вариантов).

Таким образом, происходит следующее:

1. Берется список индексов от `1` до `l` (`l` - требуемая длина пароля)
2. Каждому индексу сопоставляется набор вариантов (он задан как `const s` - то есть номер индекса игнорируется и набор вариантов будет `s` независимо от индекса)
3. Варианты каждого индекса комбинируются в порядке исходного списка - и получается список всех возможный строк длины `l`

Answer (score 6):

## 119 символов

```
IEnumerable<string>F(char[]s,int l){return--l<0?new string[]{""}:from r in F(s,l)join c in s on 0 equals 0 select r+c;}
```

```
IEnumerable<string> F(char[] s, int l)
{
  return --l < 0
    ? new string[] { "" }
    : from r in F(s, l) join c in s on 0 equals 0 select r + c;
}
```

Чтобы можно было задавать задержку:

```
IEnumerable<string> F(char[] s, int l, int t)
{
  foreach (var r in F(s, l))
  {
    Thread.Sleep(t);
    yield return r;
  }
}
```

Проверка:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ruSO_519441___Перебор
{
  class Program
  {
    IEnumerable<string> F(char[] s, int l)
    {
      return --l < 0
        ? new string[] { "" }
        : from r in F(s, l) join c in s on 0 equals 0 select r + c;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int i = 0;

      foreach (var s in (new Program()).F("01234567".ToCharArray(), 4))
        if (Convert.ToInt32(s, 8) != i++)
          throw new Exception();

      Console.WriteLine(i);
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @May_be, ответ дополнен.

Comment: @May_be, дополнил.

Comment: `IEnumerable<string>F(char[]s,int l)=>--l<0?new[]{""}:F(s,l).SelectMany(_=>s,(a,b)=>a+b);`

Comment: @PetSerAl: почему не отдельным ответом?

Comment: @VladD Я просто немного улучшил, а не придумал с нуля.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Тогда подождём, пока @Qwertiy внесёт.`

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript ES6, 113 символов

```
(s,l)=>eval(`${t="for(q of s)".repeat(l,l=[]).replace(/q/g,(q,i)=>q+i)}l.push(${t.match(/q\d+/g).join('+')})`)&&l
```

PS: Раз уж появился F#, пусть и JS будет :)

Answer (score 3):

## 71 <s>82</s> <s>92</s> символа

Версия на F#:

```
let rec p (l:char seq)=function
|0->seq{yield[]}
|k->seq{for s in p l (k-1) do for c in l->c::s}
```

Это, конечно, не C#, но тоже .NET, так что можно использовать с программами на C#.

Тестовый код:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    p ['a'; 'b'; 'c'] 4
       |> Seq.map (fun arr -> new string(arr |> List.toArray))
       |> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
    0
```

Развёрнутое состояние:

```
let rec combinations allowed = function
    | 0 -> seq { yield [] }
    | k -> seq { for s in combinations allowed (k-1) do for c in allowed -> c::s }
```

---

Типовыводитель рулит, укоротил:

```
let rec p l=function
|0->seq{yield[]}
|k->seq{for s in p l (k-1)do for c in l->c::s}
```

---

По совету @PetSerAl, можно уложить в одну строку:

```
let rec p l=function 0->seq{yield[]}|k->seq{for s in p l (k-1)do for c in l->c::s}
```

---

Можно сэкономить ещё пару символов, если перейти к спискам:

```
let rec p l=function 0->[[]]|k->[for s in p l (k-1)do for c in l->c::s]
```

Comment: `seq{yield[]}` -> `Seq.empty`. Также символ `|` перед первым вариантом не является обязательным.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Хм, вроде ж `Seq.empty` возвращает _пустую_ последовательность, а мне нужна одноэлементная, состоящая из `[]`.

Comment: Да, чего-то я сглупил. Хотя, вроде проверял, работало. Значит, что-то не то проверял.

Comment: @PetSerAl: И у меня без стартового `|` не скомпилировалось. Выдаёт `error FS0010: Unexpected keyword 'let' or 'use' in binding. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token.` на последующем `let main ...`

Comment: Я пишу такую команду в FSI: `let rec p l=function 0->seq{yield[]}|k->seq{for s in p l (k-1)do for c in l->c::s} in p [1..3] 3;;` — и он её прожёвывает.

Comment: @PetSerAl: О, можно ж в одну строчку! Гениально!

Comment: `seq{yield[]}` -> `[[]]:>_ seq`

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 42 символа

```
g s 0=[""];g s l=do{x<-g s$l-1;y<-s;[y:x]}
```

Развернутый вариант, для понимания:

```
gen :: [Char] -> Int -> [String]
gen chars 0 = return ""
gen chars len = do
  x <- gen chars (len-1)
  y <- chars
  return $ y:x

main = print $ gen ['a', 'b', 'c'] 3
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 45 символов

```rb
->a, n{a.repeated_permutation(n).map(&:join)}
```

Функция (лямбда/проц), принимает массив  символов и число, возвращает последовательность (перечислитель, генератор, `Enumerator`) *перестановок его элементов с повторениями*.

Но есть беда: он **не ленивый** (из-за `.map(&:join)`) и на сколько-нибудь больших входных данных он сожрёт всю память и упадёт. Но требований к этому не ставилось `:)`

Починить этот досадный недостаток можно всего за <s>$9.99</s> +5 символов:

```rb
->a, n{a.repeated_permutation(n).lazy.map(&:join)}
```

---

```rb
                        вот так ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

## [r](/questions/tagged/r) 38 символов

```
do.call(paste0,expand.grid(rep(s,l)))
```

где s-массив символов которые можно использовать,
l-длина

Пример :

```
s=list(letters[1:3])
l=2
do.call(paste0,expand.grid(rep(s,l)))
[1] "aa" "ba" "ca" "ab" "bb" "cb" "ac" "bc" "cc"
```